# Can't use navigation.dispatch() inside useEffect

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

I am trying to prevent the user use the back button, I found a solution in the [react-navigation](/questions/tagged/react-navigation) docs
as they say, I must use this code:

```js
navigation.dispatch(
    CommonActions.reset({
      index: 1,
      routes: [
        { name: 'Login' },
  
      ],
    })
  );
```

So I used it inside `useEffect` in order to apply it on page load.

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  navigation.dispatch(
    CommonActions.reset({
      index: 1,
      routes: [
        { name: 'Login' },
  
      ],
    })
  );
},[])
```

But I am getting this error and the app does not work well:

> Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

Comment: what is `some` ? and are you on the login screen trying to reset to Login screen ?

Comment: Ah, that was nothing, I tried to use a hook instead of an empty [ ] to hopefully prevent re-renders :)). but edited that. I need to prevent user from pressing back button on the login page.

Comment: is this useEffect inside Login page ?

Comment: yes it is inside the login page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is useEffect with [] is called when the component mounts. So the component mounts then you tell it to reset navigation to login page(same page) so Login gets remounted and useEffect called again. And so on and so on. So what you need to do is that the component that sends you to login needs to do the reset and remove it from useEffect inside the login Page.

Comment: No problem. Keep it up!